# jqGrid ignores first keystroke after showing alert/confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i have a requirement to show a confirmation message before editing a cell. User can either choose to use a auto-calculated value or can enter new value in the Col 2. If user chose to use the auto-calculated value, next cell (Col 3) should be put in edit mode.

I am using code shown below, so when user tabs thru Col 1 to Col 2, it displays a confirmation dialog box. When user clicks Cancel on the dialog box, the focus remains in Col 2 and if user clicks on Ok focus is set to Col 3.

The problem here is that, after closing the dialog box, when i try to type in the textbox, the first keystroke is ignored and nothing happens. However subsequent keystrokes work fine.

Strange thing is that, if i click directly in Col 2, everything works fine (first keystroke is not ignored). Issue happens only when i navigate from Col 1 to Col 2 by pressing tab.

Please help me fix this issue.

```
$(gridId).jqGrid({
    colNames: ["Id", "Name", "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"],
    colModel: [
            { name: "Id", index: "Id", hidden: true, key: true, formatter: 'text' },
            { name: "Name", index: "Name", width: '165px', align: 'left', resizable: false, editable: false, classes: 'non-editable', formatter: 'text' },
            { name: "Col1", index: "Col1", width: '60px' },
            { name: "Col2", index: "Col2", width: '60px' },
            { name: "Col3", index: "Col3", width: '60px' }                        
        ],
    hidegrid: false,
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
    scroll: true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    height: 370,
    datatype: 'json',
    viewrecords: true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    ignoreCase: true,
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        userdata: "userdata"
    },
    url: gridUrl,
    editurl: '#',
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    footerrow: true,
    multiselect: false,
    //autowidth: true,
    cmTemplate: {
        //Default col model properties, if not using default, override in the colmodel 
    resizable: false,
    edittype: "text", //for checkbox, override in the colmodel 
    align: "right",
    editable: true,
    formatter: 'number', //for text, override in the colmodel 
    formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: "", decimalPlaces: 1, defaultValue: '', align: "right" },
    editrules: { number: true} //Setting numeric validation for all columns as all the editable columns are numbers
},
beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    var grid = $(this);

    if (prevCellName != cellname && cellname == "Col2") {
        var autoCalculated = 123;
        var response = confirm("The Col 2 auto-calculated value is " + autoCalculated + ". Would you like to use this value?");
        if (response == true) {                         
            setTimeout(function () {
                grid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, "Col2", autoCalculated);
            }, 10);

            setTimeout(function () {
                grid.jqGrid('editCell', iRow, iCol + 1, true);
            }, 20);

        }
    }
    prevCellName = cellname;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Oleg, can you please help :)

Comment: Which fork of jqGrid (old jqGrid in version <=4.7, [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) you use and in which version? If it's really the bug of the cell editing, then it needed be fixed, but it can be fixed only in newest version of jqGrid: in the *current* code from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid).

Comment: @Oleg, we are using jqGrid v4.4.3